# why isn't the .a in my Xcode swift static library project after I successfully build build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Created Swift static lib, imported some .c and .h files, built without errors, but .a doesn't show up in Xcode Proj Nav on the left.

[image]

Comment: This is normal. Outputs generally do not appear in the project navigator. They're in DerivedData.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode choose Product > Show Build Folder in Finder to locate the library you built.